# Verification of unclear test results

Tags: exam-questions, future-perfect

I have done some online test and I wonder of two questions:

We __________ to our new house by August.

- will move ✗
- **will have moved**
- will been moving
- will moved

What would a native speaker use? Which variant is more often?

Which sentence correctly summarizes the meaning of the sentence: ‘Why don’t we postpone the meeting until next week?’ the chairman said.

- **The chairman announced that the meeting would take place the next week.**
- The chairman suggested that the meeting had been postponed. ✗
- The chairman proposed that they call off the meeting.
- The chairman said they wanted the meeting postponed.

My feeling is that none of the options is correct. The chairman proposed a concrete date.

Comment: It's better to ask only one question at a time! For the first one, the last two options are ungrammatical. _Will move_ is possible, but _will have moved_ is the most likely. I agree with you that none of the options for Question 2 is quite correct. I would say "The chairman suggested that the meeting [should] be postponed".

Comment: I see, thank you. The ungrammatical options are intentional - it helps to reduce the number of potential choices.

Comment: If you use the singular they then the last option for Q2 is possible as the they could refer back to the chairman who when they suggested it may have also wanted it.

Comment: True, that is why I skipped this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.

We **will have moved** to our new house by August.

---

Q2.

‘**Why don’t we postpone the meeting until next week?’ the chairman said**.

why don't we = suggestion or proposal

postpone = to delay an event and plan or decide that it should happen at a later

---

Answer **The chairman proposed that they call off the meeting.**

*The chairman **suggested** that the meeting **should not happen until next week***:

---

**postpone**; verb; to delay an event and plan or decide that it should happen at a later date or time

**proposed;** adjective; **suggested** as a possible plan or action for people to consider:

**call sth off** — phrasal verb with call verb; **to decide that something that has already been planned will not happen:**

All Ref CED [**POSTPONE**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/postpone) [**PROPOSED**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proposed?q=PROPOSED)